# How to send a request to make API calls until a boolean is true

Tags: ios, get

I'm really new to iOS and backend development so please bear with my lack of technical knowledge. I apologise for the potentially confusing title but here's my problem:

I'm trying to create an iOS app that allows the user to receive push notifications when the user's selected course's status is OPEN.

The way to check if a selected course status is OPEN is a GET request from my school's API, and a bit of parsing of the JSON response to extract the course status.

So how do I do this GET request constantly to check for the selected course's status, and send the user a push notification when it is OPEN?

It would be great if someone can point me towards a specific direction to research, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A push notification should come from a server somewhere. I think what you're looking for is a poll with a local notification if you want the app to be doing the work. The downside to this is the app has to be running for it to poll. I recommend watching [this WWDC Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/index.php?id=517) to learn more about how it works. To start the request doing the polling, you'd do something like this:

In your interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
```

And in the implementation:

```
-(void)someMethodSomewhere
{
      // Create a timer and automatically start it.
      self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f // some number of seconds 
                              target:self
                            selector:@selector(checkStatus) 
                            userInfo:nil 
                             repeats:YES];

}

-(void)checkStatus 
{
    // Perform request, check course status

    if (/* course status is open */) 
    {
        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
        notification.alertBody = @"The course is now open";
        notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

        // Stop the timer
        [self.timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

---

## Edit

To make it run in the background, you should probably read [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20). The upshot is that you need to override the `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` selector on your AppDelegate and from there call the `checkStatus` method from above. You can't, however, control how often this will get called. That's the job of the OS and to some degree the user's preferences. At the end of the processing, be sure to call the completion handler.

You must also set a minimum interval for fetching. In your app's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, you'll need to add something like this:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
{
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
    return YES;
}
```

And assuming the code from above is also in the AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
{
    [self checkStatus];
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

You'll also have to set a property in your app's Info.plist file. You'll need to add the key `UIBackgroundModes` with the `fetch` value.

Comment: But can the timer run when when the app is closed by the user?